# how to fix "the size of byte buffer and the shape dont match" in kotlin tflite

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, kotlin, tensorflow-lite

im getting :

```
    Process: com.example.qutubcomplexmonumentspredictiontensorflowlite, PID: 24696
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match.
        at org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.SupportPreconditions.checkArgument(SupportPreconditions.java:104)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer.loadBuffer(TensorBuffer.java:309)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer.loadBuffer(TensorBuffer.java:328)
        at com.example.qutubcomplexmonumentspredictiontensorflowlite.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-1(MainActivity.kt:40)
        at com.example.qutubcomplexmonumentspredictiontensorflowlite.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$hODd9Y72uZ7cKE8WuAJp-ZdH6JA(MainActivity.kt)
        at com.example.qutubcomplexmonumentspredictiontensorflowlite.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onClick(D8$$SyntheticClass)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5246)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10565)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1194)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21200)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

MainActivity.kt:
https://gist.github.com/0xN1nja/537ec6ad7d00c2284d7788f92de0a600
My model :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should resize your input buffer size same as the ML model parameter.